# Delete row from ListView created by Custom Adapter in onClickListener

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, arraylist, android-custom-view

Hi i get my data from a server and pass them in my Custom Adapter to populate my ListView. Below is my custom Adapter code:

```
public class AppointmentAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private AppointmentAdapter adapter;
private Activity activity;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
HashMap<String, String> todo = new HashMap<String, String>();
 // String confirmation;
RelativeLayout confirm_corner;


public AppointmentAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String,        String>> d) {
    activity = a;
    data=d;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    //imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
}

public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}



public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    //View vi=convertView;
    //if(convertView==null)
       final View  vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.appointments_list_item, null);
    adapter = new AppointmentAdapter(activity,data);
    TextView aid = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.aid); // id
    TextView apptitle = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.apptitle); // title
    TextView starts_date = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.starts_date); // created_at
    TextView starts_time = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.starts_time);
    TextView contact = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.contact);
    TextView confirmation = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.confirmation);
    confirm_corner = (RelativeLayout)vi.findViewById(R.id.confirm_corner);

    //CheckBox check = (CheckBox)vi.findViewById(R.id.tododone); // checkbox


    todo = data.get(position);

    // Setting all values in listview
    aid.setText(todo.get(AppointmentsFragment.TAG_AID));
    apptitle.setText(todo.get(AppointmentsFragment.TAG_APPTITLE));
    starts_date.setText(todo.get(AppointmentsFragment.TAG_STARTDATE));
    starts_time.setText(todo.get(AppointmentsFragment.TAG_STARTTIME));
    contact.setText(todo.get(AppointmentsFragment.TAG_CONTACT));
    confirmation.setText(todo.get(AppointmentsFragment.TAG_CONFIRMATION));
    String test = todo.get(AppointmentsFragment.TAG_USER_EMAIL);
    //Handle buttons and add onClickListeners
    ImageView accept = (ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.accept);
    ImageView deny = (ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.deny);
    //String test = confirmation.getText().toString();
    //&& (!test.equals(MainActivity.user_email))
    Log.d("CONFIRMATION: ", MainActivity.user_email);
    if (confirmation.getText().toString().equals("pending")  ){
        Log.d("PASS CONFIRMATION: ", confirmation.getText().toString());
        confirm_corner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    accept.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) { 
            //do something
            confirm_corner = (RelativeLayout)vi.findViewById(R.id.confirm_corner);
            Log.d("Button accept: ", MainActivity.user_email);
            new Confirm_appointment().execute();
            //vi.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            confirm_corner.setVisibility(View.GONE);


        }
    });
    deny.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) { 
            //do something
            Log.d("Button deny: ", MainActivity.user_email);
            new Deny_appointment().execute();
            confirm_corner.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            //adapter = new AppointmentAdapter(this,data);
            data.remove(position);
            data.clear();
            data.addAll(data); 
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });


    return vi;
}
```

I want when i click on the deny button that row to be removed. What should i change in my code to get this fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't create a new `AppointmentAdapter` inside the `AppointmentAdapter`. When you try to `notifyDataSetChanged()` after you removed a row you then notify the wrong adapter. You notify the newly constructed adapter which is not the one that has changed data. (The newly constructed ones are not attached to the listview either so they couldn't make sure the notifications reach that anyway.)

You should remember that only a single adapter is needed to work together with the a ListView which has multiple item Views. You construct one adapter per item view but that wont work. The adapter is supposed to cooperate with the ListView and not with the item views.

There are many things I would do different with your code and I think you should implement the View Holder pattern. You can read about it [here](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html).

**update**

Instead of calling `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` you have to call it on `this`. Where `this` should be the adapter where you just removed the row. Because you are using anonymous (non-static) inner classes for the `View.OnClickListener` you can reach the outer class by using `AppointmentAdapter.this`, which is the adapter that you want.

Try this:

```
deny.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) { 
        //do something
        Log.d("Button deny: ", MainActivity.user_email);
        new Deny_appointment().execute();
        confirm_corner.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        AppointmentAdapter.this.data.remove(position);
        AppointmentAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

By the way, I agree with Willis that the lines where you clear out your data and reload it seems just wrong. So I threw them out too.

Comment: when i delete the new AppointmentAdapter i get an NullExceptionError in the adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() . Can you please paste some code you think will work

Comment: That would be because now `adapter` is never assigned and thus stays null. You don't need that variable at all, remove the line `private AppointmentAdapter adapter;` as well. Check my updated answer for more help.

Answer (score 1):

What is the purpose of the following two calls?:

```
data.clear();
data.addAll(data);
```

To remove an element from your `ListView` simply call `data.remove(position)` and then update the `Adapter` (`adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`). See if that works.

Comment: when i use your method it dosen't update the ui automatically. i have to swipe the tab that includes the fragment and when i return the row is gone. Shouldn' t it do it automatically?

Comment: Why is the `onClickListener` in you `Adapter` `getView` method? You should put the listener in your `Fragment` and delete the rows from there.

Comment: I saw many examples using the onClickListener inside the getView when it was a button of each row.

Comment: Oh okay I misunderstood the application. Each row in your `ListView` has a deny and accept `Button`, as opposed to only two `Button`s for the entire UI?

Comment: if i use the Listeners in my Fragment how should i get the position of the row that i click the button?

Comment: Are there two `Button`s in each `ListView` object or two `Button`s total?

Comment: they are enabled in specific rows from the if statement just above the first onClickListener